# Creating file using GPT API and extract it’s content in nodejs

Tags: node.js, gpt-4

I need to upload any file and create it with **chatgpt api**. In this case, I get a successful result.

To extract the content, I use the `openaiGPT.beta.assistants.create Gpt4` API, which is also successful.

But somehow I am not able to extract the content from this file.

I am using the model `gpt-4-0125-preview` and the tool type `retrieval` and I am still not able to extract the content of the file.

I have also tried the **thread API** and can create the thread, but when I try to create a message and run the API for GPT4, I get an error message.

> 401 You do not have sufficient permissions for this operation. Missing
> areas: api.threads.write. Check that you have the correct role in your
> organisation (reader, writer, owner), and if you are using a
> restricted API key, that it has the required scopes.

I have also granted the authorisation.

For threads, I use the following APIS

- `openaiGPT.beta.threads.messages.create`
- `openaiGPT.beta.threads.runs.create`

Does anyone have any ideas on this topic?

Many thanks in advance!

I want to upload a file and extract the content with GPT4.